# Code not color coordinating in blueJ

Tags: java, bluej

Here is the part of the code that I am talking about,

```
 public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent e)
            {
                startGame(Scenario);
            }
        });
    }

    JMenuItem saveItem = new JMenuItem("Save_game");
    saveItem.addActionListener (new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent e)
        {
            saveGame();
        }
    });
    gameMenu.add(saveItem);

    JMenuItem loadItem = new JMenuItem("Load_game");
    loadItem.addActionListener (new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent e)
        {
            loadGame();
        }
    });
    gameMenu.add(loadItem);

    JMenuItem quitItem = new JMenuItem("Quit);
    quitItem.addActionListener (new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent e)
        {
            quit();
        }
    });
    gameMenu.add(quitItem);

    JMenuItem aboutItem = new JMenuItem("About_'Shade'");
    aboutItem.addActionListener (newActionListener() {
        **public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent e)
        {
            openAbout();**
        }
    });
    helpMenu.add(aboutItem);

    JMenuItem playItem = new JMenuItem("How_to_play_'Shade'");
    playItem.addActionListener (new ActionListener() {
        **public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent e)
        {
            openHelp();
        }**
    });
```

The first four public void expression are isolated correctly with yellow highlight, the last two aren't. Is there an explanation for this as they're all formatted the same way.
I am also not getting a highlighted yellow for any public void under that section of code.
Screenshots:
[Screenshot1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U640E.png)

[Screenshot2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zUeHZ.png)

Comment: Can you provide a picture, or a link to the picture if you can not upload photos here?

Comment: Look at the highlighting, especially in the vicinity of `new JMenuItem("Quit);`.

Comment: That section is highlighted correctly, It's the sections under it that aren't. I've posted two screenshots.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is missing a double quote in:

JMenuItem quitItem = new JMenuItem("Quit");

Maybe that's it?